# Vectorization of for loop in Julia

Tags: performance, optimization, julia, vectorization, mathematical-optimization

I am attempting to address a straightforward optimization problem in Julia, but the execution speed is considerably slowed down due to a lengthy for-loop. Are there any methods to enhance the performance?

```
using Optim

function f(a, b, x)
    obj = (x[1] - a)^2 + b
    return obj
end

initial_guess = [1.0]

a = randn(5000000)
b = repeat([0, 1], inner = 2500000)
result = Vector()


for i in 1:5000000
    param_q = optimize(x -> f(a[i], b[i], x), initial_guess, NelderMead())
    param_q = Optim.minimizer(param_q)
    result = push!(result, param_q)
end
```

I believe vectorization may be a crucial approach, isn't it?

Comment: Just FYI: loops are fast in Julia, so there is no relative performance in going from loop to vectorized expression. In addition to choosing a better optimization algorithm, you should also follow the general performance tips: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/

Comment: Is `f(a, b, x)` you provide here the objective function you want to minimize, or is it an example? Because a much faster way to get to the result in this example is `result = a`.

Comment: This is just an example !
I know that analytical solution is the best way !

Answer (score 1):

In this case the biggest gain would be by changing the optimization algorithm used:

```
julia> function f(a, b, x)
           obj = (x - a)^2 + b
           return obj
       end
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @time result = map(a, b) do ai, bi
           param_q = optimize(x -> f(ai, bi, x), -10.0, 10.0)
           param_q = Optim.minimizer(param_q)
           return param_q
       end;
  1.194795 seconds (10.08 M allocations: 806.584 MiB, 21.98% gc time, 3.63% compilation time)
```

The only drawback is that the variant I used requires providing a search range (I put -10 to 10), but typically it is easy to decide.

Comment: Thank you. 
That response was incredibly quick. 
If possible, can you provide more details on why it's significantly faster? 
What were the issues with the optimization algorithm I provided? 
Is Nelder-Mead inherently slow? And why isn't it necessary to specify an initial value in this code?

Comment: Yes, Nedler-Mead is slower than the algorithm I used. And also yes - you do not need to provide an initial value, instead you provide a range in which the algorithm should look for a solution (and this means that the algorithm could converge to a boundary if there is no minimum within the interval).